# If modifiying Peterson's algorithm with memory barriers where can you place the barriers?

Tags: c, concurrency, thread-safety, locking, memory-barriers

I have recently been studying locks in shared-memory systems and we have looked at Peterson's algorithm, a thread-safe procedure for entering critical regions, whilst maintaining mutual exclusion. The algorithm can be seen below:

```
bool interested[2] = {false,false}; 
int turn;

void enter(int me, int other) {
  interested[me] = true;
  //memory barrier 1
  turn = me;
  //memory barrier 2
  while(interested[other] && (turn == me)) ;
}

void exit(int me) {
  interested[me] = false;
}
```

This algorithm runs into trouble if the threads are on different machines... On a single device , commands are reordered such that the semantics of the program are maintained; however, if multiple cpus are sharing a resource then they may have different orderings for the same code.

We could have one thread running `turn = other` before `interested[me] = true`, and the other in the correct order. If a context switch occurs after `turn = other` and another thread attempts to enter the critical region, they can because the value in `interested` is false still. This means that, after a context switch back, both threads can enter the thread, which breaks mutual exclusion.

This can be fixed using [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#example), which preserve order before and after the barrier. I have read and been told that the solution is to place such a barrier in the location, annotated above as *memory barrier 2*, before the while. This works because it enforces the ordering constraints before and after; in this instance, that means that the order of the array update and variable assignment is preserved.
My question is as follows:

Would placing it at memory barrier 2 work?
My initial thoughts are yes because it would enforce the array update first.

Comment: To actually write this in C, you need `_Atomic bool interested[2];` and `_Atomic int turn;`.  You can then use `atomic_load_explicit()` to do relaxed loads/stores, and `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` to place a full barrier somewhere, preventing StoreLoad reordering between storing and checking the result.  Using non-atomic variables and memory barriers is less safe than you might think, as https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/ explains.  (It's talking about Linux kernel code, where `volatile` is supported as a kind of memory_order_relaxed atomic by relevant compilers like GCC.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you. If  this were improved to use atomic variables, aslong as the memory barrier is after the first statement and before the while statement, would it work?

Comment: No, you need a StoreLoad barrier (`thread_fence(seq_cst)` between `turn=me` and the loads (your barrier 2 location), as well as a StoreStore barrier (part of `thread_fence(release)`) between the two stores (barrier 1).  I'm not totally sure if you also need to order the two loads wrt. each other, like checking `turn` last.  If so, you could load them into local temporaries in separate statements, making it possible to put an `acquire` fence between them.

Comment: Or if you mean just using `_Atomic` variables without any `atomic_load_explicit(relaxed)`, then you wouldn't need any separate fences; the default memory_order is `seq_cst` for loads, stores, and RMWs like `x++`.  And a C11 program without data-race UB will behave as if it's entire execution was sequentially-consistent.  (SC-DRF)  (The point of Peterson's algorithm is mutual exclusion without any atomic RMWs, but it notably is one of the few things where seq_cst memory ordering is actually useful, not just acquire / release / acq_rel which are fine for most programs if you have atomic RMWs.)

Answer (score 0):

Placing the barrier at *memory barrier 1* would not work because, whilst `interested[me]` definitely happens first, the `turn==me` might occur before the `turn = me` asignment, on one cpu and not the other, meaning the loop would enter because the second part of `while (interester[other] && turn==me)` would be false, even though it shouldn't be.

The situation is dependent on the system, but I believe this to be true for the general principle of memory barriers.

Comment: Your answer implies that no barrier is needed between the two stores, but I'm not totally sure that's true, and your answer doesn't explain why not.  I'd have guessed they need to become visible to other cores in the same order they're read, but I haven't verified the logic.  It's quite possible that barriers are needed in both locations.  (With barrier 1 being just StoreStore, and barrier 2 being a full barrier that includes StoreLoad.  https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ / https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/)

Comment: Oh, and you'd need an acquire fence after the spin-loop, to order the critical section wrt. taking the lock and seeing the other thread's store that unlocked.